# Oracle SQL fails when variable in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I just switched from SQL Server to Oracle and I'm confused about how to get results when I'm using a variable who's value isn't set based on a result from sql query.  What on earth is wrong with this?

```
variable firstDate date; 
variable secondDate date;
exec firstDate := '03/01/2019';
exec secondDate := '03/31/2019';

select 
   c.xent_id  
FROM 
   lic c 
WHERE 
   C.EXPR_DTE >= TO_DATE(firstDate,'MM/DD/YYYY') 
   AND C.EXPR_DTE <= TO_DATE(secondDate,'MM/DD/YYYY') 
   AND c.clnt_cde = 8801
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a `DATE` bind variable in SQL* Plus / SQL developer. It maybe defined as a `VARCHAR2` and assigned a string and converted where needed. Also, note that you are missing colons at appropriate places before the bind variables. Check the query to see how it's used. You may put the same expressions in your where clause of the actual query.

```
variable firstDate VARCHAR2; 
variable secondDate VARCHAR2;
exec :firstDate := '03/01/2019';
exec :secondDate := '03/31/2019';


select TO_DATE(:firstDate,'MM/DD/YYYY') dt1 , TO_DATE(:secondDate,'MM/DD/YYYY')
 as dt2 from dual;

DT1      DT2     
-------- --------
01-03-19 31-03-19
```

Comment: I need to use those variables in the following statement: select c.xent_id FROM lic c WHERE C.EXPR_DTE >= TO_DATE(firstDate,'MM/DD/YYYY') AND C.EXPR_DTE <= TO_DATE(secondDate,'MM/DD/YYYY') AND c.clnt_cde = 8801 ;

Comment: @Clos : Go ahead and use it , what's stopping you?

Comment: when i try and use it i get an error report:  Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
ORA-06550: line 5, column 76:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "DT2": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Comment: @Clos : You didn't tell us that you are using that SQL statement in a procedure / PL/SQL block. I  answered it in SQL context and if you want to use the same in a PL/SQL scope you need a variable to hold  the selected column, i.e. `xent_id`

Comment: like i mentioned above...I'm very new to Oracle, I've been reading, but not finding what I need.  I have been able to declare variables but not use them in my where statement.  If you look at the very top where I posted, that is what I need to do, I just don't know how to do it correctly.  I cannot make a stored procedure or a function (long story) I need to be able to execute the script and get the results.

Comment: @Clos : Well, In that case it would be hard for me to explain you the whole concept given the limited time we voluntarily spare here in SO. Good luck with exploring more in SO for other answers  to arrive at the solution you desire for this question or a new question with more details.